# VideoView не открывает видео из глаереи

Tags: java, android, gallery, videoview

Я совсем новичок в программировании. Решил написать код плеера, который сможет загружать видео из галереи в VideoView. Поэкспериментировал с ImageView сначала, и все работает нормально, но с VideoView проблемы - не открывает видео. Чувствую что разгадка на поверхности, но не хватает опыта. Помогите пожалуйста!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.vpbaimbve;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private final int Pick_image = 1;

    private VideoView videoView;
    private final int Pick_video = 2;

    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Связываемся ImageView:
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        //Связываемся VideoView:
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

        //Связываемся с нашей кнопкой Button:
        Button PickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Настраиваем для нее обработчик нажатий OnClickListener:
        PickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Вызываем стандартную галерею для выбора изображения с помощью Intent.ACTION_PICK:
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                //Тип получаемых объектов - :
                photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
                //Запускаем переход с ожиданием обратного результата в виде информации об изображении:
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);
            }
        });
    }

    //Обрабатываем результат выбора в галерее:
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case Pick_image:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    try {

                        //Получаем URI изображения, преобразуем его в Bitmap
                        //объект и отображаем в элементе ImageView нашего интерфейса:
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            case Pick_video:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    final VideoView videoView2;
                    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
                    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                    videoView.setVideoPath(String.valueOf(Pick_video));
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                    videoView.start();

                }

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.912"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.928"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/black_ops_one"
        android:text="Open Video"
        app:backgroundTint="#651FFF"
        app:backgroundTintMode="add"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        app:iconPadding="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
        app:iconTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.064"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.921"
        app:strokeColor="#000000" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="581dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Android studio при сборке ошибок не выдает. Писал на версии андройда 4.1, проверяю на телефоне с 10 версией. Эмулятора нет, amd проц. Запускает приложение нормально.

Comment: обратите внимание на `videoView.setVideoPath(String.valueOf(Pick_video));` там должен быть путь к видеофайлу, а вы туда отправляете целое число

Comment: Я понимаю что в этой строке проблема, но я не понимаю как нужно указать путь к файлу, который был выбран через галерею, именно какая команда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы запустить видео - нужно указать путь к нему в эту строку

```
videoView.setVideoPath(String.valueOf(Pick_video));
```

сам путь берем так же как и изображение с помощью Uri

```
final Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
```

а вот дальше могут возникнуть проблемы с получением реального пути, для обычных файлов достаточно `String path = uri.getPath();`, а для файлов из галереи нужно писать функцию - [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047555/7540461) (почитайте ответы с этого вопроса или с [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546101/7540461)) так же знаю что на андроид 10 еще чуть сложнее получить реальный путь к файлу

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду разбираться